# Heap Corruption detected after Normal Block (#193) at 0x014E5A28

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was doing a code in which I have to create a dynamic array and a pointer (the pointer should be used to move through the data of the array). I have to make methods get (to return the index of a number to be searched in the array), update (when get method returns the index the update method can update the value), length(this method should return the size of the array), next(this method should move the pointer to the next index of the array), start(this method should move the pointer to the start of the array), end(this method should move pointer to the end of array) and Add(it should add a block to the array)

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Runner
{
private:
    int *arr;
    int *ptr;
    int size;

    // to input in array

    void Input()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++,*ptr++)
        {
            cout << "Enter value no. " << i + 1 << "\t";
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
    }

    //to allocate memory
    void Create()
    {
        cout << "Enter the total number of elements :\t";
        cin >> size;

        arr = new int[size];
        ptr = arr;

        Input();
    }

public:
    //constructor to define starting value
    Runner()
    {
        ptr = NULL;
        size = 0;
        arr = NULL;
    }

    //get function
    int get(int num)
    {
        bool NotNull = false;
        int index = 0;

        do
        {
            if (ptr != NULL)
            {
                ptr = &arr[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++,*(ptr++))
                {
                    if (num == *ptr)
                    {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                NotNull = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Create();
            }
        } while (!NotNull);

        return index;
    }

    //update function
    void Update(int num)
    {
        int val;
        int index = get(num);

        cout << "Enter value to update :\t";
        cin >> val;

        ptr = ptr + index;
        *ptr = val;
    }

    //length function
    int length()
    {
        if (ptr == NULL)
        {
            Create();
        }

        return size;
    }

    //moving pointer back
    void Back()
    {
        bool NotNull = false;

        do
        {
            if (ptr != NULL)
            {
                *(ptr--);
                NotNull = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Create();
            }
        } while (!NotNull);
    }

    //moving pointer forward;
    void Next()
    {
        bool NotNull = false;

        do
        {
            if (ptr != NULL)
            {
                *(ptr++);
                NotNull = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Create();
            }
        } while (!NotNull);
    }

    //to point at the start of array
    void Start()
    {
        bool NotNull = false;

        do
        {
            if (ptr != NULL)
            {
                ptr = &arr[0];
                NotNull = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Create();
            }
        } while (!NotNull);
    }

    //to move pointer to the end
    void End()
    {
        bool NotNull = false;

        do
        {
            if (ptr != NULL)
            {
                ptr = &arr[size - 1];
                NotNull = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Create();
            }
        } while (!NotNull);
    }

    //to add a block into array
    void Add()
    {
        int NewSize = size + 1;
        int *temp = new int[NewSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        size = NewSize;
        ptr = temp;
        if (arr != NULL)
        {
            delete[] arr;
        }
        arr = NULL;
        arr = temp;
        cout << "You have been provided a new block to add 1 data entry\n";
        cout << "Enter value :\t";
        cin >> arr[size - 1];
    }
};

int main()  //main made just for testing above method's working
{
    Runner *obj = new Runner();

    obj->get(3);
    obj->Update(20);
    cout << obj->length() << "\n";
    obj->Next();
    obj->End();
    obj->Back();
    obj->Start();
    obj->Add();

    delete obj;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Well the part of code giving me error is the Add method in which i have to increase the size of array without using `realloc()`.

The Add Method is as follows:

```
void Add()
    {
        int NewSize = size + 1;
        int *temp = new int[NewSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        size = NewSize;
        ptr = temp;
        if (arr != NULL)
        {
            delete[] arr;   //the point where heap corruption error occurred
        }
        arr = NULL;
        arr = temp;
        cout << "You have been provided a new block to add 1 data entry\n";
        cout << "Enter value :\t";
        cin >> arr[size - 1];
    }
```

Help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Some how you are going out of bounds. I can't debug this in my head. You probably need to spend more time with your debugger.

Comment: I don't get it clearly why deletion of dynamic array causes index out of bounds?

Comment: It doesn't, previous out of bounds writes are detected when the memory is deallocated

Comment: Agreed, the corruption happened at some point before it was detected when the deletion occurred.

Comment: If I were to guess it would be the usage of ptr.

Comment: The problem is solved it was the memory leakage error

Comment: ***memory leakage error*** A memory leak should not cause corruption of the heap.

Comment: But now the code is working fine

Comment: Unfortunately some times undefined behavior causes your broken code to appear to work fine.

Comment: You can see the code in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two statements in `Update`

```
    ptr = ptr + index;
    *ptr = val;
```

will set pointer to some value relative to the last value, which was set in the preceding call to `get`.  This will cause `ptr` to refer to memory beyond the allocated space for `arr` if the value was found in the second half of the array.  When you assign the value with `*ptr = val;` you are at best writing to the wrong array element, at worst writing to memory you don't own.  The "Heap Corruption" error detects this.

The solution would be to set `ptr` using `arr` instead:

```
ptr = arr + index;
```

since `ptr` may point past the end of the allocated space if the number was not found (and `index` would be 0).